# Locking a WinForms window when another form is shown?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, delegates, locking

I have a WinForms application, And somewhere in the program user can bring up another form like pop up window for example an About Us form. I want the main form to be locked (eg User can not do anything in the UI of main form). And when that pop-up window is closed the main form would be return to normal state.

This is my code (I think I only miss the way of locking my main form)

```
private void buttonAbout_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     AboutUS abUs = new AboutUS();
     abUS.Show()
     this.LOCK!!!  /* How to lock current form? */

     abUS.FormClosing += delegate { /* How to Unlock main form */ };
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display small form while main form is "locked"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064002/display-small-form-while-main-form-is-locked)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Form.ShowDialog()` instead of `Form.Show()`.

Also see [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064002/display-small-form-while-main-form-is-locked).